# How to do filter-mapping with servlet-name in Guice Servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, guice

In my web.xml I have

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>authFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.mystuff.AuthFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>authFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>requestFactoryServlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Servlets -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>requestFactoryServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>symbolMapsDirectory</param-name>
        <!-- You'll need to compile with -extras and move the symbolMaps directory 
            to this location if you want stack trace deobfuscation to work -->
        <param-value>WEB-INF/classes/symbolMaps/</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>requestFactoryServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/gwtRequest</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and I am attempting to convert this to use Guice Servlet configuration rather than the web.xml  configuration.

I cannot figure out how to do the equivalent of the  of the    in Guice.  I only see examples of how to filter patterns, not specific servlets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define a Guice listener in web.xml :

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>xxx.GuiceServletConfig</listener-class>
</listener>
```

And implement this listener :

```
public class GuiceServletConfig extends GuiceServletContextListener {

    @Override
    protected Injector getInjector() {
        return Guice.createInjector(new ServletModule() {

            @Override
            protected void configureServlets() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("symbolMapsDirectory", "WEB-INF/classes/symbolMaps/");
                serve("/gwtRequest").with(RequestFactoryServlet.class, params);


            }

        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Actually your sample is not complete: you don't have authFilter mapped to the servlet which was the subject for this question. I am still looking for such answer...